# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError for grpc?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, grpc, grpc-python

I just started working on grpc with python and faced problem when I import grpc.

```
    import grpc // no module named grpc
```

I'm working on vscode on my MacBook and have tried below to solve this.

```
    pip3 install grpcio
    pip3 install grpcio-tools
    python3 -m pip install grpcio
    python3 -m pip install grpcio-tools
```

All above give output:
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio in /user/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages

I have also tried below command

```
    python3 -m pip install --hidden-import=pkg_resources
```

Output gives me various other tags listed below.

[image]

I'm new to grpc and wasted many hours finding the solution on internet, even chatgpt failed me. Plz kindly help here.